# How to clear ordering when using .first() in django

Tags: python, django, database

I have a query in database as follows. Whenever I try to do a .first() on the query, The equivalent query that gets run in the database is as follows

```
SELECT *  FROM “user" WHERE UPPER("user"."email"::text) = UPPER(%s) **ORDER BY** "registration_user"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

I want to get rid of the order by clause as it interferes with indexes being applied correctly in the db and is also a costly operation. How can I refactor the code below?

```
users = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email)
users.query.**clear_ordering**(True)
if users.count() > 0 :
    return users.first()
```

Comment: If you do not specify an ordering, then that would return a random element, which is not a good idea. Anyway, `.first()` adds an extra ordering. If you use `users[0]` you remove the ordering.

Comment: If you're writing a query that may return multiple rows (and thus need to call `first`), you need some way to determine which row is returned; otherwise it would be indeterminate. You could change what column is being used to sort by calling sort by on another column, but at least one column needs to be sorted to use first().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no ordering is specified, that would mean that two calls with `.first()` can return a different element, and non-determinism often results in a lot of problems.

The `ORDER BY pk` is added by the [**`.first()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first) call, so it is not part of your `query` at all. If the queryset has no ordering, then `.first()` will add an ordering by `pk` (primary key), as is described in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first):

> **`first()`**
>
> Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or `None` if there
>   is no matching object. **If the `QuerySet` has no ordering defined, then
>   the queryset is automatically ordered by the primary key**. This can
>   affect aggregation results as described in Interaction with default
>   ordering or `order_by()`.

If you really do not want an ordering, you can *subscript* the queryset:

```
users = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email)
if users.exists():
    return users[0]
```

But that does not look like a very good idea. If no order is specified, then the database can return *any* record that matches the filtering condition, and it can thus return a different record each query.